# How can a Ruby class detect the process name that runs it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, irb

I am using delayed_jobs to run Ruby classes, how can the Ruby detect the name (command) of the process that is running it?

any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can determine the name of the file using `$0`. You can even set the process name using it like so `$0 = 'foo'`[Dave Thomas's blog post](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/11/trivial-request-logging-for-rails.html). If you want to get the command line args, you want to look at `ARGV`.

Comment: By the way, the `$0` variable is aliased by `$PROGRAM_NAME`

Comment: Nice. That's a lot less confusing a name.

Answer (score 2):

`$0`         Contains the name of the script being executed. (May be assignable so it can go wrong)

Comment: ruby-prof's `--replace-progname` switch manipulates $0 for this very purpose, so the `$0 == __FILE__` magic incantation in the script being run still works.

Answer (score -4):

If you are are using Unix system you can execute script from ruby to determine process like this:

```
`ps aux | grep ruby`
```

and then use $? to get the process

Comment: This will show *every* ruby process on the system, not just the script in question.